# How to calculate MoM and YoY?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have requirement where I need to get the MoM and YoY values for all the metric columns.
MoM column should have last month values and same is the case with YoY.
I am able to do it with one dimension but as there are many dimension so getting wrong information.

Below is the query which is working when I put filter for all dimension :-

```
SELECT section,region,country,type,device,month,page_views,
LAG(page_views, 1) OVER (ORDER BY month) as MoM,
LAG(page_views, 12) OVER (ORDER BY month) as YoY
FROM table_name
Where region = 'RUCIS'
 and Country = 'Russia'
 and section ='METRICS' 
 and type_visits = 'All Visits'
 and device = 'Non Mobile Devices'
```

Which is working fine but if I remove the where condition as there are many region and many countries , in that case it does not work.

Below is some sample data [image]

How can I do it for all dimension?

Comment: Are you sure that this query relates to mysql? There is no OVER operator in mysql.

Comment: @Sharad . . . If your code is working, then it is not MySQL.  I removed the mysql tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the code works with a `where` clause, but you want it work work without one, then you can use `partition by`:

```
SELECT section, region, country, type, device, month, page_views,
       LAG(page_views, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY section, region, country, type_visits, device
                                ORDER BY month) as MoM,
       LAG(page_views, 12) OVER (PARTITION BY section, region, country, type_visits, device
                                 ORDER BY month) as YoY
FROM table_name
WHERE region = 'RUCIS' and
      Country = 'Russia' and
      section ='METRICS' and
      type_visits = 'All Visits' and
      device = 'Non Mobile Devices';
```

You should now be able to remove the `WHERE` clause or to adapt it to your needs.